# Print without showing print view in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i call PrintElem function  a  popup opens in new window(it shows print view). I don't want to show that any popup just direct print without any view.
Tried even hiding pop also still its redirecting /opening a window.

```
button click__html+='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick = "PrintElem(\'.modal-body\');" >
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Print</button>';

function PrintElem(elem){Popup($(elem).html());}

function PrintElemview(elem)
{
     Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) 
{       
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=auto,width=auto');
        mywindow.document.write('<html ><head><title></title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/printpage.css">');         
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body style="width:320;height:450;border:1px solid black;marrgin-left: auto;padding:10px!important;">');                
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css' media = 'print'>@page {size:A5;}@page :left {  margin-left: 3cm;}@page :right { margin-left: 4cm;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.boreer{border-bottom-style: double!important;}</style>");  
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.printdespbill > td{border: 1px solid black; border-top: none!important;border-bottom: none;border-collapse: collapse;}</style>");              
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.table-bordered{ border: 1px solid black!important;}</style>"); 
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>body{ width: 6.5inc!important;font: 10px/1 'Open Sans';align:center!important;}</style>");                          
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.company_header{border-bottom: 12px solid black;}.docname{margin-top: 16px!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.printabl{ margin-bottom: 12px!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.print_desp_bill > tr > td{padding: 1px !important;border-bottom:none!important;border-top: none;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.presc_dts > tr > td{padding: 3px !important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.billhead{text-align:center;text-decoration: underline;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.theadfont10px{font: 10px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.content{font: 10px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>tbody >tr > td { font: 10px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>thead >tr > td { font: 10px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.presc_hd >tr > th { font: 10px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;!important;font-weight: bold;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.table-bordered > tbody >tr >td{ border: 1px solid black!important;}</style>");         
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.table-bordered > thead >tr >th{ border: 1px solid black!important;}</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("<style type='text/css'>.table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > thead > tr > th {border-top:none!important}</style>");           
         mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();           
        location.href=location.href;

        if($('#redirect').val() == '1')
        {
            var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
            // redirect.location()
             window.location=base_url+"patient_reg";
        }
        // @media print {
        //   body { font-size: 10pt }
        // }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: basically it will open the print dialog because it's just hooking into the browser's UI, not a lot you can do about it. If you'd googled this you'd be able to read that lots of people have tried to solve it before and the results are not very satisfactory - either IE-only solutions, or 3rd-party pieces of software, or browser add-ons etc etc: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=javascript+print+without+dialog

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your time am not bother  of printer dialog. Its showing a popup with url and my print view page.

Comment: that's because you're telling it to. That's what your whole script does. If you use media queries in your CSS instead of a separate print view page, you can just call window.print directly from the original page, or allow the user to do it themselves, and they will get the printable version that way. Here's a tutorial: http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Answer (score 1):

There are some security restrictions from OS on silent printing since it can be used to print unwanted items automatically if you visit certain site which has your type of code.

Hope it helps!!